# jQuery UI sortable - Exclude Items from being dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

is it possible to exclude single sortbale items from being dropped on another list?

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGVeA/). E.g. Item 2 shouldn't be dropable on the second list.

I have really no idea if this is possible with some hacks, but unfortunately there is no option for the UI plugin :(

Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that the item (in the example it is Item 2) should still be sortable, but not dropable on the second list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW** http://jsfiddle.net/UKUfe/ (In this demo the item 2 is not droppable in list 2 but still sortable `:)`

This will help: rest code below and explanation:

**code**

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    receive: function(event, ui) {

        if ($(ui.item).hasClass("foohulk")) {
           $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

            return false;

        }

    }
}).disableSelection();


​
```

**OLD**

**demo** http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/items.html **or**  http://jsfiddle.net/GGVeA/2/

Similar question in Jquery Forum: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-i-lock-an-li-in-place-in-a-sortable-list

Good link with options et al. : http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

If you want to disable item add `.ui-state-disabled` to the item `li`, (I hear you said: why `ui-state-disabled` `:)` go to following link and read API themes and stuff: "Interaction Cues" http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API

hope this helps, :)

**code**

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: @Daniel Bro I will never ever steals anyone's code trust me on that, specially such an easy example `:)` do you reckon its hard, apart from that how are you doing? `:)` also this question a weeeeee to common : http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-i-lock-an-li-in-place-in-a-sortable-list **or** I even know the earlier parts when the enable disable had issues :) http://forum.jquery.com/topic/enable-disable-sort

Comment: fine fine, just don't get it why to post an `exact duplicate` of an already posted answer

Comment: @Daniel lol cooleos, hope you alright bruv, take care, if you want I will +1 you as well (if that makes you happy) take it easy, `:)`

Comment: You can keep the +1 (click back on the digit)... all cool , still... `exact duplicate` why spam ?

Comment: Spam? really? (I am just sharing a extra links to make it clear for OP) anyhow man, have a good one and keep my +1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this isn't solving my problem too :( Please see my edit above.

Comment: @Tats_innit Thank you very much. Thats what I was searching for :)

Comment: @Aley Glad it helped and +1 to your question :)

Comment: This does not work.  Not sure whether it's a bug in jQuery or not.  In the JSFiddle, drag Item 1 from right to left.  Now drag Item 2 from left to right.  It cancels the drop but put Item 1 back to the right too.  It always resets the last successful drop too.

Comment: Using the remove event instead, preventing the item to be removed in the first place, seems to work for me.  See http://jsfiddle.net/LSpbz/

Answer (score 2):

add `items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"` like this

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
}).disableSelection();​
```

and add `ui-state-disabled` class to *Item2* like this

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-state-disabled">Item 2</li>`
```

here jsfiddle example

[Exclude Items from being dropped jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wU3Vp/)

Also, take a look at another example

[jQuery UI Sortable - Include / exclude items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/items.html)

---

**EDIT**

Since you updated your answer it completely changes the answer

You need to make use of the `update` event of the sortable and check if the element about to be dropped is a *forbidden element*

like this

```
update:function(event, ui) {
    if(ui.item.hasClass('ui-state-disabled') && ui.item.parent()[0].id === 'sortable2') return false;                
}
```

[Exclude Items from being dropped on other sortable area](http://jsfiddle.net/wU3Vp/33/)

Comment: here you go dan man +1 but see the old refs in the post below `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not solving my problem :( I forgot to mention that the item (in the example it is Item 2) should still be sortable, but not dropable on the second list.

Comment: @Aley updated my answer , You can now choose on what sortable areas you wish to allow dropping (im my example i prevented you from dropping on area with id = sortable2)

Answer (score 1):

I found Tats_innit's answer very helpful.  One extra part I needed to add was to also hide the placeholder when an item could not be dropped.

I imagine this is a common enough addition to the problem so I thought I'd share it - you simply need to handle the `sort` event, perform the same class check and you can access the placeholder via the `ui.placeholder` object.

So in context with the previous answer's example (http://jsfiddle.net/GGVeA/2/) the complete addition would be:

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    receive: function (event, ui) {

        if ($(ui.item).hasClass("foohulk")) {
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');

            return false;

        }
    },
    sort: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).hasClass("foohulk")) {
            ui.placeholder.hide();
        } 
        else {
            ui.placeholder.show();
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
```